# error: conversion from 'const char [1]' to 'wxString' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Имеется такой код (кусок):

```
int count = data.getCount();
const XYZ* pData = data.getData();

this->CreateGrid(count, 3);

this->SetColLabelValue(0, "x"); // тут ругается
this->SetColLabelValue(1, "y");
this->SetColLabelValue(2, "z");

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    wxString str = "";
    str << pData[i].x; this->SetCellValue(i, 0, str); str = ""; // тут тоже ругается
    str << pData[i].y; this->SetCellValue(i, 1, str); str = "";
    str << pData[i].z; this->SetCellValue(i, 2, str); str = "";
}
```

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Так покажите полное сообщение об ошибке. Обычно компилятор сообщает, какие именно объявления являются неоднозначными.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/V5j5Zv1n Вот все сообщения компилятора. Здесь бы они не влезли

Comment: Попробуйте ипользовать wchar_t литералы. Например,  wxString str = L"";

Comment: Вроде помогло. Спасибо большое

Comment: Если помогло, то давайте я напишу это в ответе, а вы тем самым закроете вопрос?

Comment: Хорошо. Согласен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, проблема состоит в том, что вы компилируете программу, используя Unicode, и в этом случае неявный конструктор для строк с элементами типа `char` отсутствует.

Поэтому попробуйте использовать широкие строки, то есть с типом элемента `wchar_t`. Например,

```
wxString str = L"";
```